# Width issue with Telerik's RadLayoutControl

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, telerik

I have this **[RadLayoutControl](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/layoutcontrol-overview.html)**:

[image]

[image]

The problem I have is that when I maximize my Form, the width of the **[RadListView](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/listview-overview.html)** and the **[RadDropDownList](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/dropdown-and-listcontrol-dropdownlist-overview.html)** proportionally increases:

[image]

How I could stop this behavior?. I would like to preserve those controls width to let the gridviews occupy that extra width when scaling/maximizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **MinSize** and **MaxSize** properties of the **LayoutControlItem** hosting your controls: [link](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/layoutcontrol-items.html)